# Using substituion rule for piecewise monotonic function

Tags: integration, operator-theory

I am trying to read the ON THE EXISTENCE OF INVARIANT MEASURES FOR PIECEWISE MONOTONIC TRANSFORMATIONS paper from 1973.

One has given a map $\tau : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ which is a piecwiese monotonic $C^2$ function.
Furthermore, the operator 
$$ Pf(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\phi^{-1}([0,x])} f(s)ds$$
is considered where $\phi = \tau^N$. Since $\tau$ is piecewise $C^2$ it follows that $\phi$ is also piecewise $C^2$. Denote by $b_0,\dots,b_q$ the corresponding partion for $\phi$ and denote with $\phi_i$ the corresponding $C^2$ function. Further, define $\psi_i = \phi_i^{-1}$, $\sigma_i(x) = | \psi_i'(x)|$ and $\chi_i$ the characteristic function of the interval $J_i = \phi_i([b_{i-1},b_i])$. It is then claimed without proof that

$$ Pf(x) = \sum_{i=1}^q f(\psi_i(x))\sigma_i(x)\chi_i(x)$$
holds. But how can I see that the equation holds?

Answer (score 0):

I will show
$$ \int_A Pf(x)dx  = \int_{\phi^{-1}(A)} f(s) ds$$ for any measurble set $A$.
If I restrict $\phi_i$ to $$ \phi_i :[b_{i-1},b_i] \to \phi([b_{i-1},b_i])$$ then $\phi_i$ has an inverse and one can obtain:

$$ \begin{align}\int_A Pf(x)dx  &= \sum_{i=1}^q \int_A f(\psi_i(x))\sigma_i(x) \chi_i(x) dx \\&= \sum_{i=1}^q \int_{\phi_i(b_{i-1})}^{\phi_i(b_i)} f(\psi_i(x))\sigma_i(x) \chi_A(x) dx \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^q \int_{b_{i-1}}^{b_i} f(x) \, \sigma_i(\phi_i(x)) \, \chi_A(\phi_i(x)) \, \phi_i'(x)dx  \end{align} $$

It [holds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) that $$ \sigma_i(\phi_i(x)) = \left|\frac{1}{\phi_i'(x)} \right|.$$
Therefore, we get 
$$ \begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^q \int_{b_{i-1}}^{b_i} f(x) \, \sigma_i(\phi_i(x)) \, \chi_A(\phi_i(x)) \, \phi_i'(x)dx &=\sum_{i=1}^q \int_{\phi_i^{-1}(A)} f(x)  dx \\ &= \int_{\phi^{-1}(A)} f(x)  dx.  \end{align}$$

Note that if $\phi$ is monoton decreasing we get

$$ \int_{\phi_i(b_{i})}^{\phi_i(b_{i-1})} f(\psi_i(x))\sigma_i(x) \chi_A(x) dx = \int_{\phi_i(b_{i-1})}^{\phi_i(b_i)} f(\psi_i(x)) (\phi_i'(x))^{-1} \chi_A(x) dx $$